# How to check an email exist with Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, backend

I have a project with nodeJs and I've used the nodemailer , now I want to check that the email exists or not Does nodemailer have method that it does?

Comment: [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) is a module for Node.js applications to allow easy as cake email **sending**.  Sending, so , not for checking mail....

Comment: Do you know more way?

Comment: are you referring to valiading an email or actually checking for existence. i don't think the latter is possible. even gmail you can first send to a non existing email only to get an acknowledgement it failed